# Why does the shutter work only without film loaded on a Minolta X-370?

Tags: troubleshooting, shutter, vintage, minolta, film-cameras

Using a Minolta X-370, what does it mean if the shutter advances and releases without film but it will not release the shutter with film loaded?

Comment: This may help.  http://forums.photographyreview.com/help-files/minolta-x370-shutter-problem-fix-here-6320.html